# possible to pass variable to javascript function from html form like this?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form><input type="file" name="first" onchange="jsFunction(2);">
<input type="file" name="second" onchange="jsFunction(3);"</form>
```

Possible to pass just numbers to the js function?

Thanks

Comment: @camran - I agree, I never vote down without a comment. I would imagine that it was due to the way you formatted and worded the question. Perhaps using a complete sentence would have helped. P.S. I'm not the one who voted you down :-)

Comment: Maybe it had something to do with the way you have 80% of a test case in the question? I'd guess about 30 seconds of work and you could have found out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely plausible, however, the `onChange` event is only fired when the input has changed **AND** it loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this.  What you are really doing here is creating a function on the fly.  Your `jsFuction` executes when the page loads, not when the value changes.  So, its return value should be a function--the function that you want to execute when the value changes.  For example:

```
function jsFunction(number) {
  return function () {
    var currentValue = this.value;
    alert('I was given ' + number + ' and the current value is ' + currentValue);
  };
}
```